# Can't solve the differential equation $(2x/y^3) dx+(y^ 2 -3x^ 3) /y^4dy=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$(2x/y^3) dx+(y^ 2 -3x^ 3) /y^4dy=0$$

checked for a homogeneous, non-homogeneous, exact, non-exact solution but still couldn't solve it.

Is there an error in the equation?

($x^3$ supposed to be $x^2$)?

If not what's the solution?

Comment: Is it $y4$ or $y^4$?

Comment: oh, sorry it is y^4

Comment: You could just write $2xydx + (y^2  - 3x^3 )dy = 0$.

Comment: I copied it how it was written in the book. figured it wouldn't make a difference removing $y^4$

Comment: Were you told explicitly that you are able to solve it? Well, it is exact if you swap $dx$ and $dy$......

Comment: already tried switching $dx$ & $dy$, didn't get a very big difference. the main problem with this equation is that there was always an extra $x$ that's why I asked if there was an error because $3x^2$ would be easily solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably there is a typo in the equation which should be :
$$(2x/y^3) dx+(y^ 2 -3x^ 2) /y^4dy=0$$
$$d\left(\frac{x^2}{y^3}-\frac{1}{y}\right)=0$$